# Passing Shortcode $atts from PHP to Javascript using wp_localize_script

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, shortcode

I want to use Wordpress' `wp_localize_script` in order to pass shortcode `$atts` available to a javascript script.

It seems that `wp_localize_script` will only work in the same function where I `wp_enqueue_script` the referenced script.

I access the shortcode `$atts` in a different function.

```
function csf_enqueue () {

//other enqueued scripts

wp_enqueue_script( 'csf_script_jquery', plugins_url( 'js/path/to/file', __FILE__ ), array ( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-core') );

    $myvars = array('value' => 'one');
    wp_localize_script('csf_map_script_jquery', 'myVars', $myvars);
}
```

I want to replace `$myvars` with the shortcodes' `$atts`.

I add the shortcode as follows;

```
add_shortcode("csf_map", "csf_shortcode_ajax_frontend");
```

In `csf_shortcode_ajax_frontend()`, I access the shortcodes `$atts`.

```
function csf_shortcode_ajax_frontend( $atts, $content = null ) {

      $atts = shortcode_atts( array ( 
      'width'=> 600,
      'height'=> 400,
      'myinfo' => 'blah'
      ), $atts );  

//continues
}
```

How do I access the shortcode `$atts` in the function containing `wp_localize_script`, when wp_localize_script has (?) to contain the  `wp_enequeue_script` line?

Answer (score 1):

```
global $atts;
```

then extract the atts in your function.

```
extract($atts);
```

Hope this works for you.
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be best to create an option field in the csf_shortcode_ajax_frontend() with update_option("this_is_a_field", $atts) and then access the same database option field in csf_enqueue() when calling the wp_localize_script() hook?